# Show that $\left\{\frac{m}{mn+1}: m,n\in\Bbb N*\right\}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, natural-numbers

Let
$$A = \left\{\frac{m}{mn+1}: m,n\in\Bbb N*\right\}$$

The question is as follows:
**Show that A has an upper bound and a lower bound and determine them.**

### My attempt:

I first thought of giving inequations for m and n since they are in $\Bbb N*$, so
$m>0$ and $n>0$
meaning
$$mn>0$$
$$mn+1>1$$
$$0<\frac{1}{mn+1}<1$$
Now if we multiply each by the strictly positive integer $m$ we get
$$0<\frac{m}{mn+1}<m$$
Now we can see that $\inf A$ exists (while i am not sure how am i going to get it) Besides that i can't tell that A has an upper bound since $m$ is not a constant, i tried some way rather than multiplying and no conclusion.
So help me please and tell me if my start is right, I appreciate your opinions

Comment: Notice $m \leq mn + 1$.

Comment: Wow haha i probably wouldn't notice that thanks, so then divide each by $mn+1$ nice so there exists an upperbound. now i have to find the exact sup and inf...

Comment: And hint for finding the supremum:$$\frac{m}{mn+1} \le \frac{m}{m+1}<1$$

Comment: $\frac {m}{mn +1} = \frac {1}{n + \frac 1m}$.  If we fix $m$ and let $n$ get as large as we want we see it can tend as close to $0$ as we like.  If we fix $n$ and let $m$ get as large as we like we can get it as close to $\frac 1n$ as we like but always smaller.  The largest $\frac 1n$ can be is $1$ so if we fix $n=1$ ...

Comment: Hint for inf.  $0 < \frac {m}{(n+1)m + 1} < \frac m{(n+1)m}=\frac 1{n+1} \le \frac 1{n+\frac 1m} = \frac {m}{nm + 1}$.  Hint for sup.... well what Marco said.

Comment: @fleablood Wait so i was confused with other exercices i know that $a=inf \{n\in\Bbb N* \}$ implies that$a>n$ but not the opposite, so i thought i didn't i find inf A, but isn't 0 simply the infimum of A based on my approach?

Comment: You can prove $\inf A = 0$ by showing that for all $q\in A$, $q \ge 0$.  That's easy-- all $q\in A$ are positive.  And we must show that for all $r \in \mathbb R$ so that $r > 0$ there is a $q\in A$ so that $q < r$.  To show that we know that $\inf \{\frac 1n| n\in \mathbb N\}=0$. so there is an $\frac 1k$ so that $\frac 1k <r$ and then if we let $q=\frac 1{k+1}$ we have $q\in A$ and $0 < q=\frac 1{k+1} < \frac 1k < r$.

Comment: "Wait so i was confused with other exercices i know that a=inf{n∈N∗} implies thata>n"  I'm not following.  $a=\inf\{n\in \mathbb N_{*}\}$ does *not* imply $a > n$.  It implies that for all $n\in \mathbb N_{*}$ then $a \le n$.  And at any rate $\inf\{n\in \mathbb N_{*}\}=1$.

Comment: My point was if we look at $A = \{\frac m{mn+1}: m,n\in \mathbb N_{*}\}$ as $A=\{\frac 1{n + \frac 1m}\}$ it might be more intuitive that  for any $\frac m{mn+1}=\frac 1{n + \frac 1m}$ that we can get it as close to $0$ as we like (just let $n$ and/or $m$ be large) or as close to $1$ as we like (let $n=1$ and $m$ be large).  It's obvious $0 < \frac 1{n+ \frac 1m} < 1$ (which you weren't seeing... although you could have if you had said $n\ge 1$ so $mn \ge m$ so $mn + 1> m$ so $0< \frac 1{mn+1} < \frac 1m$ and so $0 < \frac m{mn+1} < 1$.

Comment: @fleablood "Wait so i was confused with other exercices i know that a=inf{n∈N∗} implies thata>n" ... i just realized what i just said is stupidly wrong lol, anyways what i want to know mean since i started by definition of m and n by their set then i concluded that $0 < \frac{m}{mn+1}" doesn't it mean that inf A = 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You write:

> I first thought of giving inequations for m and n since they are in N∗, so
> $m>0$ and $n>0$
> meaning
> $mn>0$
> $mn+1>1$
> $0<\frac 1{mn+1}<1$
> Now if we multiply each by the strictly positive integer $m$ we get
> $0<\frac m{mn+1}<m$

You can do better by considering $n \ge 1$ so

$mn \ge m$ and

$mn + 1 > m$ and so $0 < \frac 1{mn+1} < \frac 1m$ and $0 < \frac m{mn+1} < 1$.

Now you can see that $A$ must be bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$.

To find the $\inf$  it might help to note that $\frac m{mn+1} = \frac 1{n+\frac 1m}$.

$\frac 1{n+\frac 1m} < \frac 1n$ so $\inf A \le \inf \{\frac 1n\}$.

As for the $\sup$ it might help to note that $B= \{\frac m{m\cdot 1 + 1}\}=\{\frac m{m+1}\}\subset A$ so $\sup A \ge \{\frac m{m+1}\}$.

Comment: "$0 < \frac m{mn+1} < 1$" now what are the reasons of not admitting that $sup A$ to be 1 and $inf A$ to be 0 since the inequation didn't came from no where, you started from $n\geq1$ isn't that right?

Comment: Well, by my argument (which admittedly may be a little convoluted as I was trying to explain rather than experience instinct is that as $0 < \frac m{mn + 1} \le \frac 1n$ then $0 \le \inf\{\frac m{mn+1}\} \le \inf \{\frac 1n\} = 0$.  (Presumably you have already proven $\inf \{\frac 1n\} = 0$.)  Ans as $B\subset A$ we must have $\sup A \ge \sup A$ and $\sup B =\sup \{\frac m{m+1}\} = 1$ we have $1\le \sup A \le \sup B = 1$... Admittedly this was to get an instinct of what the limits had to be.  To actually prove them (once you know them) is much easier.

Comment: An actual proof would be $0 < \frac m{mn+1}$.  If $r> 0$ let $n>\frac 1r$ so $0 < \frac 1n < r$. Let $m=anything$.  Then $\frac m{mn+1}=\frac 1{n + \frac 1m} < \frac 1n < r$.  So $0$ is lower bound but any $r$ above $0$ is not so $0 = \inf A$.  Simularly for $\sup$. $\frac m{mn+1}= \frac 1{n+\frac 1m} < 1$.  If $w<1$ let $r=1-w>0$ and let $m> \frac 1r$ and $n=1$. Then $\frac m{mn+1}=\frac m{m+1}=1-\frac 1{m+1} > 1-r =w$.  So $1$ is upper bound but $w$ below $1$ is not so $\sup A = 1$.